# Python - Different kind of errors from two similar functions

Tags: python, exception, discord.py

I have a Discord Bot that plays an Audiofile on command in a voice channel. When that file doesnt exist, i want to handle it via `try / except` - problem is,

`discord.FFmpegPCMAudio` just prints `res/mp3s/asff.mp3: No such file or directory` directly to console, instead of triggering the `except` part.

The thing i do not understand though: When i put `open(filename, r)` into the same function, it correctly returns `[Errno 2] No such file or directory` and triggers my `except` handling.

Why do two functions in the same place that both try to access a file give two different results to my exception handling, and how can i prevent it? My first easy solution would be to manually `os.path.exist()` before calling the function, but i want to know why im having this issue in the first place.

This is roughly what my code looks like, not directly reproducable of course because youd need a running discord bot...

```
async def playAudioFile(message, audiofile, volume):
    with open('res/mp3s/{}.mp3'.format(audiofile.lower()), "r") as f:
        print(f.read())            #returns error towards my exception handler as expected

    if volume is None:
        voice_channel = message.author.voice.channel
        vc = await voice_channel.connect()
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('res/mp3s/{}.mp3'.format(audiofile.lower())))    #prints directly into console, ignores my exception handler
        while vc.is_playing() == True:
            pass
        else:
            for x in bot.voice_clients:
                if (x.guild == message.guild):
                    await x.disconnect()


@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx, argument, volume):
    try:
        await playAudioFile(audiofile=argument, message=ctx.message, volume=volume):
    except Exception as e:
        print("Ooops!" + str(e))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behaviour for Discord is to catch all exceptions, and print them to your console instead. You can, however, overwrite the default error handler by creating your own using `on_command_error()`. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/7822af90858ef65012ea500bcecf1612) a basic example of a custom error handler to get you started.

This way, you can check the type of the exception that was caught using an `if-statement` (to handle every type of exception differently), and do with it what you want.

Comment: so far so good, but how do i check for file not found errors? the example checks via `commands.NoPrivateMessage` e.g., but file not found is not a discord command error, so how could i if check for that?

Comment: Actually, i can see how it works when the command called throw the error, but the issue is that my command doesnt directly throw the error - it calls another function and within that function the error appears. i can still work with that if check if i do another check in the main command i guess though

Comment: All errors should be sent through there, so if your command calls a function that errors, your on_command_error *should* still pick it up (mine does, at least)